# Apache poi Excel: Creating a formula based on the integer index of the column

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Say that my column number is 26, when I create a formula my formula should look like, say: SUM(AA1:AA3) for example. but how do I translate 26 to AA? Or say 27 to AB? Is there a way for Apache POI to use Column index as an integer and translate it into its letter representation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339238/how-to-set-formulas-in-cells-using-apache-poi

Comment: @Hirak that is not the issue. The issue is using the Column Number as parameter instead of using a Column letter. 1 associates with B, 2 associates with C, etc. The problem is when we start getting double letters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That requires just a little code:

```
public static String columnName(int index) {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    while (index >= 26) {
        s.insert(0, (char) ('A' + index % 26));
        index = index / 26 - 1;
    }
    s.insert(0, (char) ('A' + index));
    return s.toString();
}
```

And something to test it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(columnName(25));
    System.out.println(columnName(26));
    System.out.println(columnName(52));
    System.out.println(columnName(27 * 26));
}
```

Output:

```
Z
AA
BA
AAA
```

Answer (score 9):

You'll want to use [CellReference](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html) from Apache POI. That provides the methods you need to convert

For your specific case, you want [convertNumToColString(int))](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html#convertNumToColString%28int%29):

> Takes in a 0-based base-10 column and returns a ALPHA-26 representation.

Comment: This actually makes a lot of sense that Apache POI would have it built in.

Answer (score 1):

Erwin Bolwidt has the right idea.

In english it would be:

```
num / 26 - 1 = first_letter
num % 26     = second_letter
```

So for example:

```
27 / 26 - 1 = 0 => A
27 % 26     = 1 => B
```

Thus:

```
27 = AB
```

Comment: The limit to the number of columns in Excel 2007 and newer is 16,384 - that's column name XFD [for index 16,383]. So you need 3 letters. And perhaps newer versions allow more; my function can handle up to Integer.MAX_VALUE - that would be column FXSHRXX :-)