# How to dynamically set spreadsheet auto filter in ColdFusion 2016?

Tags: coldfusion, spreadsheet, autofilter, coldfusion-2016

I would like to add dynamically auto filter to all columns in the first row on the spreadsheet. Here is example of what I have so far:

```
SpreadSheetAddAutoFilter(theSheet,"A1:Z1");
```

This works but problem is if I have less or more columns in my files. Is there a way to set filter on every column in the first row of my file? That shouldn't be hard coded. Please let me know if you have any example for this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Use [CellReference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23017309) to build the range, or rewrite it in CF from [the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.poi/com.springsource.org.apache.poi/3.9.0/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.java#CellReference.convertNumToColString%28int%29)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you already have an Excel sheet, and are trying to dynamically add the filter to the entire row, you need to

1. Get the column count
2. Translate the column count into the corresponding letter. For example column E -> 5
3. Create a range from that, such as `A1:E1` and pass that string into the `SpreadSheetAddAutoFilter()` function.

Here is a working example that I wrote:

```
<cffunction name="columnToLetter" returntype="any">
    <cfargument name="index" type="numeric">
    <cfset letterArray = listToArray('A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z', ' ')>
    <cfreturn letterArray[index]>
</cffunction>


<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="fin.xlsx" name="spreadSheetObj" sheetname="Sheet1"> 
<cfset count = SpreadsheetGetColumnCount(spreadSheetObj, 'Sheet1')>

<cfoutput>
    count: #count# <br>
    <cfset column_label = columnToLetter(count)>
    <cfset column_label = 'A1:' & column_label & '1'>
    label: #column_label#
    <cfset SpreadSheetAddAutoFilter(spreadSheetObj, column_label)>
    <cfspreadsheet action="write" filename="updatedFile.xls" name="spreadSheetObj" sheetname="courses" overwrite=true> 
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: The functions will break when the `index` is greater than 26. Instead try this [function](https://trycf.com/gist/68f77d251b081e550b7fc637fa5f7d0f/acf2016?theme=monokai)

Comment: @RRK - You should post that conversion as a separate answer

Answer (score 1):

Posting this answer since it has better results than the already posted answer.
This is just a simple loop with division by `26` and getting the character.

```
<cfscript>
    // Function to print Excel column name for a given column number
    function printString(n){
        str = '';
        while (n>0){
            // Find remainder
            rem = n%26;
            // If remainder is 0, then a 'Z' must be there in output
            if (rem==0){
                str = 'Z' & str;
                n = (n\26)-1;
            } else {
                str = chr(64 + rem) & str;
                n = n\26;
            }
        }
        return str;
    }
</cfscript>
```

Shorter form

```
function printString(n){
    str = '';
    while (n>0){
        rem = n%26;
        str = rem==0 ? 'Z' & str : chr(64 + rem) & str;
        n = rem==0 ? (n\26)-1 : n\26;
    }
    return str;
}
```

[**Function in action**](https://trycf.com/gist/68f77d251b081e550b7fc637fa5f7d0f/acf2016?theme=monokai).

Comment: +1, based on POI convertNumToColString function here: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.poi/com.springsource.org.apache.poi/3.9.0/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.java#CellReference.convertNumToColString%28int%29

Comment: The method used to find a remainder (%26) appears to work in Railo, Lucee and ColdFusion 10/11, but not CF2016 or 2018.  It must be a new CF bug.

Comment: I think you may need to add val() around "n" when using modulus... rem = val(n)%26;  I added that and it now seems to work w/CF2016 & 2018.

Comment: @JamesMoberg - Exactly what version of 2018? The example worked for me with 2018,0,02,313961. But you're right it does fail on trycf.com - version 2018,0,03,314033 . Seems to be some kind of parser bug. Add a single space before or after the "%" and it works fine `rem = n(space)%26;` or `rem = n%(space)26;`