# I'm trying to copy a Formula from one column to the next using Apache POI

Tags: java, copy, apache-poi, formula

I'm kinda new to manipulating excel files. Here's my problem. I have column 'x' on sheet 'Z' which is populated with data and has a formula (Sum). I need to copy that formula on the next column 'x+1', same sheet, after which I need to populate it with data from a result set and I don't really know how to do it (Copying the formula on the next column, that is). I only found how to manipulate cells or rows, but this is about a pretty large amount of data. Anyone have been through this so far?

Comment: Are you setting the formula yourself, or is this a formula already in one cell that you want to copy to another one?

Comment: Basically I need the flowing behavior on the new column: last cell of the new column to make the sum of the cells above. I said copy because it seems easier than to write it manually.

Answer (score 1):

[See this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339238/how-to-set-formulas-in-cells-using-apache-poi)

```
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA);
cell.setCellFormula("SUM(C70:C76)");
```