# How to get Cell Reference using Cell?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using apache poi 3.11, from CellReference, I can get rowIndex and Column Index, using following code.

```
CellReference cr = new CellReference("A1");
row = mySheet.getRow(cr.getRow());
cell = row.getCell(cr.getCol());
```

But my rowIndex and columnIndex are generated dynamically, how can I get CellReference using rowIndex and columnIndex?

```
XSSFRow row = mySheet.getRow(rowIndex); 
XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(columnIndex);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a CellReference instance using the CellReference(int pRow, int pCol) constructor of the CellReference class, and the formatAsString method of the created instance.

Answer (score 4):

You can get column in string by following static method and appending row number to result column String

```
ColString= CellReference.convertNumToColString(columnIdex)
```

Comment: Finally! After browsing for sometime, this is what I need. I have column index and row index, but I need to get that cell address (like 'A1', 'B1', etc). Most questions ask the other way around.